# Laravel - soft delete - move posts to other table

Tags: laravel, mariadb, delete-row

Is it possible work with Laravel, that it can have soft deleted items in other identical log table?
All soft deleted files in other table.

I want create on log table Event scheduler (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html) to delete all data after some time.

Comment: Laravel cannot do this out of the box, but it can't be to hard to write this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few different ways to accomplish this.  If you want to insert deleted items into another table then register a [model listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#events) on the models you want this action to happen for on the deleting event:

```
MyModel::deleting(function($model) {
    DeletedItems::create([
        // Your model fields here
    ]);
});
```

--OR--

If you want to actually delete items out of the database after a period of time since they have been soft deleted I would suggest using a [Scheduled Task](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#defining-schedules).  Since soft deleting gives you a time stamp you can reference that in your task.

For example, the following will remove all models that have been soft deleted for more than a month:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        MyModel::withTrashed()
            ->whereDate('deleted_at', '<', Carbon::today()->subMonth())
            ->forceDelete();
    })->daily();
}
```

Comment: The second solution seems really nice, but moving to other database will be fine too for some statistic purposes. Just delete from first and put data to statistic page. The first solution seems nice for logging, which i am thinking of.

Comment: Why not do both?  Instead of the model observer, in the task create the logic to insert the records you are about to delete into another table first and then delete them.